# SQL Server - SQL Cascade Change Data Type of a Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, scripting, database-schema

This is a problem as old as the hills, and nearly everyone would have encountered it. So, *I'm looking for the most common, and most solid solution.*

If I have a primary key column in a table, other tables have foreign keys linked to that column, and I want to change the data type of the column, what is the best tool for achieving this without having to write ad hoc database scripts manually, and without having to delete data? **Is there a tool for this?**

So, say for example, I have two tables

**Sale**

SaleKey (int)

Total (decimal)

**SaleLine**

SaleLineKey (int)

Sale (int)   **<- Foreign Key back to Sale**

Quantity (int)

Rate (decimal)

Lets say, I want to wholesale change the column SaleKey on Sale to a unique identifier. It means that I've got to write a database script to add the new unique identifier column on Sale, add a similar column on SaleLine, update the data in SaleLine to reflect Sale, drop the foreign and primary keys, then put new foreign and primary keys on. This is all possible but time consuming.

**Is there an application out there that will do this for me? Or, a stored proc that someone has already written?** SQL Server has cascade delete of data, **what about cascade change data type?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution with C#. You'll have to fill in the blanks in terms of ExecuteScript, and ExecuteScalar, but the logic will work as long as you are using SQL Server. This will only convert to uniqueidentifier, but it would not be hard to change it for a different data type. There are a few assumptions here. For example, this code assumes that the column you are trying to change has a maximum of one primary key. It might be a good project to move this in to an open source repo at some point. Also, this could be easily converted to T/SQL. I'm just better with C# than T/SQL.

*Warning: This is destructive code. It will indiscriminately delete indexes and keys etc. So, you must take care when running this to make sure that the resulting columns matched your intended data schema. This is only a tool for achieving the task at hand - not a bulletproof catch all solution. This has been tested fairly thoroughly in our databases though.*

```
    public void ChangeColumnDataTypeToUniqueIdentifier(string schemaName, string tableName, string columnName, bool allowsNull, ConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
    {
        string script = null;

        var tempColumnName = $"{columnName}Temp";

        var columnDataTypeString = DatabaseAdapter.SqlStatementBuilder.GetSqlDataType(ColumnDataType.UniqueIdentifier, 0, 0, 0);

        //Add the temp column
        //TODO: We should try to figure out if this needs not null, but we can rely on the schema upgrade to fix this later...
        ExecuteScript(connectionInfo,
        "alter table " +
        $"  {schemaName}.{tableName} " +
        "add " +
        $"  {tempColumnName} {columnDataTypeString}");

        var fullTableName = $"[{schemaName}].[{tableName}]";

        //Update the temp column to new values
        //TODO: this contains UniqueIdentifier specific code
        ExecuteScript(connectionInfo,
        "update " +
        $"   {fullTableName} " +
        "set " +
        $"   {tempColumnName} = NEWID()");

        ExecuteScript(connectionInfo,
        "alter table " +
        $"   {schemaName}.{tableName} " +
        "alter column " +
        $"   {tempColumnName} {columnDataTypeString} {(!allowsNull ? string.Empty : "not")} null");

        //Get the schema id of the target table
        var targetSchemaObjectId = (int)DatabaseAdapter.ExecuteScalar("select schema_id from sys.schemas where name = @Param1", new Collection<DataParameter> { new DataParameter("Param1", schemaName) }, connectionInfo, null);

        //Get the object id of the table we are modifying
        var targetTableObjectId = (int)DatabaseAdapter.ExecuteScalar("select object_Id from sys.tables where name = @Param1 and schema_id = @Param2", new Collection<DataParameter> { new DataParameter("Param1", tableName), new DataParameter("Param2", targetSchemaObjectId) }, connectionInfo, null);

        //Get foreign keys
        using (var foreignKeyData = DatabaseAdapter.ExecuteReader("select * from Sys.foreign_keys where referenced_object_id = @Param1", new Collection<DataParameter> { new DataParameter("Param1", targetTableObjectId) }, connectionInfo, null))
        {
            //Iterate through foreign keys
            while (foreignKeyData.DataReader.Read())
            {
                //Get thei object id of the table that references this
                var tableThatReferencesThisObjectId = (int)foreignKeyData.DataReader["parent_object_Id"];
                var foreignKeyObjectId = (int)foreignKeyData.DataReader["object_Id"];
                var foreignKeyName = (string)foreignKeyData.DataReader["name"];

                //Get the tables data
                using (var tableThatReferencesThisData = DatabaseAdapter.ExecuteReader("select * from Sys.tables where object_id = @Param1", new Collection<DataParameter> { new DataParameter("Param1", tableThatReferencesThisObjectId) }, connectionInfo, null))
                {

                    //Read the record
                    tableThatReferencesThisData.DataReader.Read();

                    //Get information about the table references this
                    var tableThatReferencesThisName = (string)tableThatReferencesThisData.DataReader["name"];
                    var tableThatReferencesShemaObjectId = (int)tableThatReferencesThisData.DataReader["schema_id"];
                    var tableThatReferencesShemaName = (string)DatabaseAdapter.ExecuteScalar("select * from sys.schemas where schema_id = @Param1", new Collection<DataParameter> { new DataParameter("Param1", tableThatReferencesShemaObjectId) }, connectionInfo, null);

                    //Get the name of the column that references the original column
                    var foreignKeyColumnName = (string)DatabaseAdapter.ExecuteScalar
                        (
                        "select " +
                        "   COL_NAME(fks.parent_object_id, fkcs.parent_column_id) " +
                        "from " +
                        "   sys.foreign_keys fks " +
                        "inner join " +
                        "   Sys.foreign_key_columns fkcs " +
                        "on " +
                        "   fkcs.constraint_object_id = fks.object_id " +
                        "where " +
                        $"   fks.object_id = {foreignKeyObjectId}", new Collection<DataParameter> { new DataParameter("Param1", tableThatReferencesShemaObjectId) }, connectionInfo, null);

                    //The new target temp column name
                    var tempForeignKeyColumnName = foreignKeyColumnName + "Temp";

                    //Concatenate the name of the table that references the original table
                    var tableThatReferencesFullName = $"[{tableThatReferencesShemaName}].[{tableThatReferencesThisName}]";

                    //Add the temp column
                    //TODO: We should try to figure out if this needs not null, but we can rely on the schema upgrade to fix this later...
                    ExecuteScript(connectionInfo,
                    "alter table " +
                    $"   {tableThatReferencesFullName} " +
                    "add " +
                    $"   {tempForeignKeyColumnName} uniqueidentifier");

                    //Update the data in the temp column
                    script =
                    "update " +
                    $"   {tableThatReferencesFullName} " +
                    "set " +
                    $"{tempForeignKeyColumnName} = " +
                    "   ( " +
                    "       select " +
                    $"           {tempColumnName} " +
                    "       from " +
                    $"           {fullTableName} referencedtable " +
                    "       where " +
                    $"            {tableThatReferencesFullName}.[{foreignKeyColumnName}] = referencedtable.{columnName} " +
                    "   )";
                    ExecuteScript(connectionInfo, script);

                    //Drop the original foreign key
                    script =
                    "alter table " +
                    $"   {tableThatReferencesFullName} " +
                    "drop " +
                    $"   {foreignKeyName} ";
                    ExecuteScript(connectionInfo, script);

                    DropIndexesForTable(tableThatReferencesShemaName, tableThatReferencesThisName, foreignKeyColumnName, connectionInfo);

                    //Drop the old column
                    script =
                    "alter table " +
                    $"   {tableThatReferencesFullName} " +
                    "drop column " +
                    $"   [{foreignKeyColumnName}] ";
                    ExecuteScript(connectionInfo, script);

                    //Rename the new temp column to the old one
                    ExecuteScript(connectionInfo, $"EXEC sp_rename '{tableThatReferencesFullName}.{tempForeignKeyColumnName}', '{foreignKeyColumnName}', 'COLUMN'");
                }
            }
        }

        var pkName = (string)DatabaseAdapter.ExecuteScalar($"select name from sys.key_constraints where parent_object_id = @Param1 and type = 'PK'", new Collection<DataParameter> { new DataParameter("Param1", targetTableObjectId) }, connectionInfo, null);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pkName))
        {
            //Drop the old primary key
            script =
            "alter table " +
            $"   {fullTableName} " +
            "drop " +
            $"   {pkName} ";
            ExecuteScript(connectionInfo, script);
        }

        var defaultConstraintName = (string)DatabaseAdapter.ExecuteScalar(
        "select " +
        "    dc.name " +
        "FROM " +
        "    SYS.DEFAULT_CONSTRAINTS dc " +
        "inner join " +
        "    sys.all_columns ac " +
        "on " +
        "    ac.object_id = @ObjectId and " +
        "    dc.parent_column_id = ac.column_id " +
        "where " +
        "    parent_object_id = @ObjectId and " +
        "    ac.name = @ColumnName", new Collection<DataParameter> { new DataParameter("ColumnName", columnName), new DataParameter("ObjectId", targetTableObjectId) }, connectionInfo, null);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(defaultConstraintName))
        {
            //Drop the old primary key
            script =
            "alter table " +
            $"   {fullTableName} " +
            "drop constraint" +
            $"   {defaultConstraintName} ";
            ExecuteScript(connectionInfo, script);
        }

        DropIndexesForTable(schemaName, tableName, columnName, connectionInfo);

        //Drop the old column
        script =
        "alter table " +
        $"   {fullTableName} " +
        "drop column " +
        $"   {columnName}";
        ExecuteScript(connectionInfo, script);

        //Rename the new column to the old one
        ExecuteScript(connectionInfo, $"EXEC sp_rename '{fullTableName}.{tempColumnName}', '{columnName}', 'COLUMN'");
    }

    private void DropIndexesForTable(string schemaName, string tableName, string columnName, ConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
    {
        //find indexes dependent on this column
        string script = "SELECT " +
        "   SchemaName = s.name, " +
        "   TableName = t.name, " +
        "   IndexName = ind.name " +
        "FROM " +
        "   sys.indexes ind " +
        "INNER JOIN " +
        "   sys.index_columns ic ON ind.object_id = ic.object_id and ind.index_id = ic.index_id " +
        "INNER JOIN " +
        "   sys.columns col ON ic.object_id = col.object_id and ic.column_id = col.column_id " +
        "INNER JOIN " +
        "   sys.tables t ON ind.object_id = t.object_id " +
        "INNER JOIN " +
        "   sys.schemas s on t.schema_id = s.schema_id " +
        "WHERE " +
        "   ind.is_primary_key = 0 and" +
        "   s.name = @SchemaName and " +
        "   t.name = @TableName and " +
        "   col.name = @ColumnName";
        using (var obstructingIndexData = DatabaseAdapter.ExecuteReader(script, new Collection<DataParameter> { new DataParameter("SchemaName", schemaName), new DataParameter("TableName", tableName), new DataParameter("ColumnName", columnName) }, connectionInfo, null))
        {
            while (obstructingIndexData.DataReader.Read())
            {
                var indexSchema = obstructingIndexData.DataReader["SchemaName"];
                var indexTable = obstructingIndexData.DataReader["TableName"];
                var IndexName = obstructingIndexData.DataReader["IndexName"];

                ExecuteScript(connectionInfo, $"drop index [{indexSchema}].[{indexTable}].[{IndexName}]");
            }
        }
    }
```